# OOP-Design: Interface-Methods with implementation-dependent parameters

Tags: java, interface, methods, parameters

The subject says it already:

I am thinking right now about following design-problem: I define an interface for a specific type of object that contains various methods.
Now i have the problem, that different implementations of this interface, need additional/different method-parameters (because the way they are implemented makes this necessary), which i cannot incorporate into the interface because they are not common to *all* interface-implementations.

Now i realize that interface implementations could come with their own property-files, loading their additional parameters from there, but what if these parameters need to be passed in at runtime?

Currently i can only think of passing in a `Map<String, Object> parameters` to overcome this problem - since JDK-Classes like [DocumentBuilderFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) are doing something very similar by providing methods like `setAttribute(String attName, Object attValue)` this
seems like a feasible approach to solve this problem.
Nevertheless i would be interested in how others solve issues like this, alternative ideas?

I dont want to derive from the interface and add additional methods, since in my case i would then have to throw `NotImplementException` from the methods of the base interface.

**UPDATE**:

What could be eventual problems of the Map-approach? Implementing classes are free to ignore it completely if they cant make use of additional parameters.
Others might check if the Map contains the desired parameter-names, check the type of their values and use them if valid, throw an exception if not.
I have also seen this being used for the abstract class JAXBContext, so it seems to be a common approach..

**UPDATE**:

I decided to go for the map-approach, since i dont see any obvious disadvantages and it is being used in the JDK as well (yes, i know this does not necessarily mean much :)
Since i cannot accept an answer on this question, i will just upvote. Thanks for your input!

regards,

--qu

Comment: Is this information something a method will need or something the object needs to perform it's actions? Give a concrete example. Using **Map<String,Object>** is a horrible design decision.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares I realize that this solution is far from optimal (thats why i asked this question), but take the DocumentBuilderFactory as an example - the interface is identical for all possible DOM-Parsers, yet different DOM-Parser-Implementations offer different features/parameters which you could never all incorporate into the interface, yet you need a way to pass in those parameters somehow at runtime - i mentioned how the JDK solves this...

Comment: Think about it, this is an **initialization** process. The factory sole purpose is to create a new object that is ready to do it's work, it's **interface** is not changed at all. What you want is something else, you want to add this to your **interface methods**. If what you want is really setup the object during initialization, make these objects constructor parameters and that is it.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares I might have expressed myself incorrectly: These parameters are not known at object-creation time (if they were, i would solve it as you suggest) - rather they are just known at runtime, to the client of the interface..

Comment: Then you don't have a general **interface**. You probably have interfaces that look alike. You can fix this at the interface client end or just give up using a general interface in this case.

Comment: you can answer yourself, stating the solution you chose and accept that answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You should just initialize each inheritor with its own specific required parameters and let the interface method remain parameter-less, as in:

Interface `Runnable`:

```
public interface Runnable {
    public abstract void run();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class MyRunnable {

    private final String myConcreteString;

    public MyRunnable(String myConcreteString) {
        this.myConcreteString = myConcreteString;
    }

    public void run() {
        // do something with myConcreteString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

couldn't you design subinterfaces that extend your (super)interface? 
anyhow I see a design problem if you need a method with different parameters depending on the implementation!

edit: code to clarify

```
interface CommonBehaviour
{
    void methodA(int aParam);
}

interface SpecificBehaviour extends CommonBehaviour
{
    void methodB(int aParam, int anotherParam);
}

class SpecificBehaviourImpl implements SpecificBehaviour 
{
   void methodA(int aParam)
   {
      //do something common
   }

   void methodB(int aParam, int anotherParam)
   {
      //do something specific
   }
}

CommonBehaviour myObj = new SpecificBehaviourImpl();
```

EDIT: You may benefit from the Command pattern: 
"Using command objects makes it easier to construct general components that need to delegate, sequence or execute method calls at a time of their choosing without the need to know the owner of the method or the method parameters."
(source: wikipedia)

I don't think the `Map` approach to be any good, I may accept it as a **fix** of existing code that would allow you to have any parameter number and type, but without formal checks! You're trying to define a common behavior (interface methods) given a variable, runtime, state.

Comment: I could, but if i did this because an implementation can not implement the methods of the base-interface, i would still need to implement them but throw a NotImplementedException - a design that i also dont like too much..

Answer (score 1):

The point of the interfaces is to have something that is common to all implementations. By trying to do this you destroy the whole reason why interfaces exists.

If you absolutely must do that there is a simple enough way that I have used before.

My answer is in C++ because I'm just not that fluent in other languages. I'm sure there are ways to implement this in java as well.

`SomeMethod(void* parameterData);`

`void* parameterData` is a pointer to a struct containing your data. In each implementation you know what you are receiving. You can even have a enum to tell you what kind of data you are receiving.

`SSomeData* data = (SSomeData)parameterData`

EDIT:

Another approach would be to create a new interface for the parameters: `IParameterData`.
Inside that interface you have 2 methods: `GetParameter(name)` and `SetParameter(name)`.
For each implementation of your primary interface you create a implementation of `IParameterData`.

I hope it helps

Comment: Well, translated to Java, this would be the approach i mentioned in my question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't realize that what you said is the Java version of what I said. I'm preparing a edit with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Can you invert the problem, and implement an interface on the user of these objects which they can query for the additional parameters?

So, when you instantiate these objects implementing the common interface, you also pass in (e.g. to their constructor) an object which provides a way of accessing the additional parameters they might require.

Say your interface has a method 'doSomething' taking parameter 'a', but you have an implementation that needs to know what 'b' is inside this 'doSomething' method. It would call 'getB' on the object you provided to it's constructor to get this information.

Comment: @quaylar - Does that help at all?

Comment: For me it seems this just adds in a layer of indirection. The client of the interface-method knows that there is a set of possible parameters, but that not all implementations "understand" all of them.
At the time of object-creation, these parameters are not known, so i cannot pass them in via the constructor. They are received by the interface-client, so there is also no way of specifying a delegation-object as you are suggesting..

Comment: I was suggesting that the interface-client is the delegation object..instead of having a `heresYourExtraData(someStringMap)` method on your interface, you have `queryMe(this)` - but yes the devil is in the details.

Answer (score 0):

You should introduce **parameter object** representing a super-set of possible arguments.

Comment: Of course that's the most simple variant, you can subclass it to make design more readable.

Answer (score 0):

In your place, I would consider finding appropriate design pattern to your problem, rather then try to bend the interface methods to suit your needs. Look into [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) for starters.